# Java Process Http Request From Azure Service

Tags: java

What is the best way to trigger a message process on a client device when an http request is sent to it. For example, say I have a web service running that is triggered by an http request running on the cloud, and it needs to alert the client device that a message has been sent to it. I don't want to have a loop on the client device that constantly checks for new messages, as that would be inefficient

Answer (score 0):

The are 2 common solutions for the scenario you describe:

1. [Long Polling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/)
2. [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)